# zoom value returning wrong in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

This is my div

```
<div class="imgBox" id="imgBox" style="margin:auto;zoom:100%;">
//content
</div>
```

When I alert the zoom value in my script

```
alert(parseInt(document.getElementById("imgBox").style.zoom));
```

It is returning correctly as 100 in IE9, but returning wrongly as 1 in IE8.

What is the issue here???

Thanks

Comment: `zoom` is non-standard I would rather use `transform: scale(n)` to make it work in more browsers, and for IE8, well, just leave the beast rest.

Comment: IE9 does not return `100`. It returns `100%`. Now `100%` does mean  `1`. It's the same amount.

Comment: @Mr Lister- No IE9 returning 100, not 100%.

Comment: That's odd, it returns `100%` for me here. Oh well.